# gtk treeview pix text cell renderer

Tags: c, gtk

I want to replace a GtkCList with GtkTreeView, but I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish the same functionality as the gtk_clist_set_pixtext function. I'm guessing I need a custom cell render. Does somebody have a free implementation I can use or am I on my owning in having to write one from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question

see section 5.3 on this link
http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/gtk-question-index.html

Basically, you stuff two renderers into the same widget

---

Here is some same code I found to accomplish what I want.

```
  cell_renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_pixbuf_new ();
  gtk_tree_view_column_pack_start (column,
                                   cell_renderer,
                                   FALSE);
  gtk_tree_view_column_set_attributes (column, cell_renderer,
                                       "stock_id", 1, NULL);
  cell_renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new ();
  gtk_tree_view_column_pack_start (column,
                                   cell_renderer,
                                   TRUE);
```